# Scaling explanatory variable by constant in multivariate linear regression

Tags: linear-model, multivariate-regression

Suppose I have a model with $n$ observations $$Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{1i} + \beta_2 x_{2i} + \varepsilon_i$$ and suppose that I obtained estimates $\hat Y$, $\hat \beta_1$, and $\hat \beta_2$ from this model.

If I redefined the $x_{1i}$'s in this model by scaling it with some constant $k$, so something like $x_{1i}' = k \cdot x_{1i}$, and then try to obtain the new estimates for
$$ Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{1i}' + \beta_2 x_{2i} + \varepsilon_i
$$ how would/wouldn't the estimates change? I have some intuitions ($\hat \beta_1$ will probably change, but $\hat \beta_2$ probably wouldn't, unsure about $\hat Y$ but my guess is it wouldn't), but I don't know the math behind it well enough to support my intuitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is good. If you think about $y$ as blood pressure, $x_1$ as weight in pounds and $x_2$ as daily alcohol consumption, it makes sense that only the coefficient for weight changes as you switch from pounds to kilograms. Mathematically it is easy to show:

The estimated coefficients are
$$ 
\hat{\beta}_0 = \bar{y} - \hat{\beta}_1 \bar{x}_1 - \hat{\beta}_2 \bar{x}_2
$$
$$
\hat{\beta}_1 = \frac{\sum x_2^2 \cdot \sum x_1 y - \sum x_1 x_2 \cdot \sum x_2 y}{\sum x_1^2 \cdot \sum x_2^2 - (\sum x_1 x_2)^2}
$$
$$
\hat{\beta}_2 = \frac{\sum x_1^2 \cdot \sum x_2 y - \sum x_1 x_2 \cdot \sum x_1 y}{\sum x_1^2 \cdot \sum x_2^2 - (\sum x_1 x_2)^2}
$$
If you carefully substitute $x_1$ with $k\cdot x_1$ to obtain $\hat{\beta}'_0$, $\hat{\beta}'_1$ and $\hat{\beta}'_2$, you will see that
$$
\hat{\beta}'_0 = \hat{\beta}_0, \,\,
\hat{\beta}'_1 = \frac{1}{k}\hat{\beta}_1,\,\,
\hat{\beta}'_2 = \hat{\beta}_2, \,\,
\hat{y}' = \hat{y}
$$